# ¿Cómo editar este código para que apareza un control DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

¿Cómo editar este código para que apareza un control DateTimePicker?

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastBuy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastBuy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastBuy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español Nestor. Por favor solo usa las etiquetas adecuadas a la pregunta. ASP es una tecnología **demasiado antigua** y absolutamente no relacionada a las nuevas tecnologías de Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción mas general, para que funcione en la mayoría de los navegadores, es usar Jquery.
Debes agregar los scripts correspondientes y los controles que quieres el datepicker serán class="datepicker". Yo recomiendo utilizar @Html.TextBoxFor() en vez de EditorFor, ya que este ultimo  a veces se pone difícil personalizarlo en sus propiedades.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(function () {
            $j.datepicker.setDefaults($j.datepicker.regional["es"]);
            $j(".datepicker").datepicker({
                firstDay: 1,
                lang: 'es',
                dayOfWeekStart: 1
                , changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
                mask: true,

                onSelect: function () {
                    // The "this" keyword refers to the input (in this case: #someinput)
                    this.focus();
                }

            });


<script>

 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastBuy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastBuy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastBuy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fecha, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker", @value = DateTime.Now.Date })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si usas html podrias definirlo usando `type="date"`

[HTML Input Types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

```
<input type="date" ...>
```

Para que funcione en asp.net mvc solo deberias indicarlo en el model con el atributo `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`

```
public class xxModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? LastBuy{ get; set; }
}
```

---

Sino puedes asegurar compatibilidad con html podrias usar el datepicker de jquery

[jquery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

solo tienes que agregar

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#LastBuy").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Por supuesto necesitas referenciar los `.js` de `Jquery` y `Jquery UI`